# Scala importing a file in all files of a package

Tags: scala, import

I need to use an implicit ordering that has been defined in an object in a file

```
abc
```

in the following way:

```
object abc{
implicit def localTimeOrdering: Ordering[LocalDate] = Ordering.fromLessThan(_.isBefore(_))
}
```

So, I make a package object

xyz

inside a file 'package.scala' that in turn is in the package 'xyz' that has files in which I need the implicit ordering to be applicable. I write something like this:

```
package object xyz{
import abc._
}
```

It does not seem to work. If I manually write the implicit definition statement inside the package object, it works perfectly. What is the correct way to import the object (abc) such that all of its objects/classes/definitions can be used in my entire package 'xyz' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot import the `implicit` conversions in that way, you will have to:

Manually write them inside the object:

```
package obj {
   implicit def etc//
}
```

Or obtain them via inheritance/mixins:

```
package obj extends SomeClassOrTraitWithImplicits with AnotherTraitWithImplicits {
}
```

For this reason, you usually define your `implicit` conversions in `traits` or `class` definitions, that way you can do bulk import with a single `package object`.

The usual pattern is to define a helper `trait` for each case.

```
trait SomeClass {
   // all the implicits here
}
object SomeClass extends SomeClass {}
```

Doing this would allow you to:

```
package object abc extends SomeClass with SomeOtherClass with AThirdClass {
// all implicits are now available in scope.
}
```

Comment: Building on your answer it's always good practice to put your implicits in a trait and then you can have a companion object extend it: `trait abc { implicit def ...}` and `object abc extends abc`. This way you can import it: `import abc._` and mix the implicits in to another class: `object obj extends abc`. Thus giving you all the flexibility you would ever need.